Different colors for each table row, without counting rows that have a specific class
I have a table and I want to color every other row, except the rows that have the noColor class, and on top of that, I don't want those rows to count towards the 2n part of the CSS.
HTML:
<table>
    <tr> <!-- normal color -->
        <td>whatever</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- css color -->
        <td>whatever</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="noColor"> <!-- normal color -->
        <td>whatever</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="noColor"> <!-- normal color -->
        <td>whatever</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="noColor"> <!-- normal color -->
        <td>whatever</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- again normal color because the rows before shouldn't count -->
        <td>whatever</td>
    </tr>
</table>

CSS:
<style>
    table tr:nth-child(2n) td{
        background-color: rgba(219, 219, 219, 0.75) !important;
    }
</style>

I tried changing my css to this:
table tr:not(.noColor):nth-child(2n) td{
  background-color: rgba(219, 219, 219, 0.75) !important;
}

/* also tried this but the result is the same*/

table tr:nth-child(2n):not(.noColor) td{
  background-color: rgba(219, 219, 219, 0.75) !important;
}

This prevents the color change for the rows, but it counts them as part of the 2n.

Use nth-child selector with "even" value.
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_striped

What you're trying to accomplish could be done using :nth-child's of <selector> syntax.
So in your case it should be:
table tr:nth-child(2n of table tr:not(.noColor)) td {
  background-color: rgba(219, 219, 219, 0.75) !important;
}

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#the_of_selector_syntax
